# Why does calling pwsh lead to an `Assembly with same name is already loaded` error?

Tags: powershell, import-module

I have a script that is run using legacy Windows Powershell 5 and is not compatible with Powershell Core (v.7+). I can't migrate this large script at this time. This script delegates out to some child scripts, and I'd like to be able to use Powershell 7+ features in some of them. My initial solution was to use:

```
    pwsh -WorkingDirectory . -File .\Configure.ps1
```

However, `Configure.ps1` imports a module and it errors out on the import with:

```
    Import-Module: path\to\script\Configure.ps1:3
Line |
   3 |  Import-Module CustomModule
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Assembly with same name is already loaded
```

The `CustomModule` has `IISAdministration` as a required dependency. Anyway, it turned out the issue was reproducible just calling the same code from a Powershell 7.3.3 session and wasn't related to the old Powershell version at all. If I invoke the script directly:

```
   .\Configure.ps1
```

It runs just fine.

Why does this happen, and is there some way to work around this assembly conflict?

Comment: This may be just a posting artifact, but note that `-WorkingDirectory .`  is passed as _arguments to your script file_ rather than setting the working directory - all arguments _after_ `-File <script>` are invariably treated as arguments to pass to `<script>`.

Comment: This may or may make a difference, but you can place `-NoProfile` before `-File` to suppress profile loading, which not only will speed things up (assuming profiles are defined), but also has the potential of avoiding the loading conflict.

Comment: Ok, I switched it to `pwsh -WorkingDirectory . -File .\ConfigureLocally.ps1`. Same error, but definitely something I missed.

Comment: Adding -NoProfile worked, which is VERY interesting. That is a good lead, thanks.

Comment: It gets weirder. Adding -NoProfile works for a 7.3.3 shell calling pwsh, but not for a 5.1 shell.

Answer (score 1):

So I still haven't figured out the WHY, but I did come up with a work-around with some help from the comments. Using `&` to invoke `pwsh` and adding `-NoProfile` worked:

```
    & pwsh -NoProfile -WorkingDirectory . -File .\Configure.ps1
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Note that whether or not `&` is used should not make a difference (if it did, it would be a serious bug).